# How Can I Display Custom Attribute Below Products Price

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-options

I need to display custom attribute below my product price, how can i get custom attribute and display on products price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use below code to get your attribute.

> $_product->getData('yourattributecode');

2. Go to your theme `template/catalog/product/view.phtml file`.
3. Search below code.

> ```
>  <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
> ```

4. Paste your code after this, for example.

> echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
>
> $_product->getData('yourattributecode');

5. Design it accordingly, do not forget to remove the cache and check.

Comment: does path right

Comment: /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme327k/template/catalog/product

Comment: Does path right ??

Comment: Yes, you can go with view.php

Comment: No line what u mentioned...

Comment: Check or fing getpricehtml in the file

Comment: could u pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48917/http-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-146774-how-can-i-display-custom-attrib

Comment: could you pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48917/http-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-146774-how-can-i-display-custom-attrib